# django-like frameworks?

Tags: java, .net, django, frameworks

Hi I've been working with Django for a few months and find it really helpful. Is there a similar framework for other programming languages such as Java or C#?
The problem I have with Django is finding a server to host the project because supporting servers are more expensive and harder to find.

In Django I find the following items useful: the object-relational mapper, admin interface and url management.

Thanks!

Comment: Added .net and java tags to draw the relevant people to this question. ASP.net MVC might be appropriate - I believe stack overflow is written with it: http://www.asp.net/mvc/

Comment: You can create the Dynamic Data Site in Visual Studio 2010, which does the same thing like Django-admin site. It requires Entity Framework.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're only looking for an alternative because of the hosting aspect of it, I suggest you simply find suitable hosting as opposed to throwing away the framework you like.

If you are looking for a good Django host, I HIGHLY recommend [Webfaction](http://www.webfaction.com).

If they're not your cup of tea, check out [djangofriendly.com](http://www.djangofriendly.com), which has a huge list of good Django hosts.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for the cheapest hosting then PHP is probably your choice. The downside is that PHP is a horrible cobbled together language, and a lot of the PHP code out there is equally terrible (par for the course, I suppose).

Answer (score 1):

Actually since django can run on fcgi, its theoretically possible to run it on *any* shared host. Here's some instructions for site5 http://www.codekoala.com/blog/2008/installing-django-shared-hosting-site5/

Getting hosting for django should be much easier and cheaper than java and asp.net.

Answer (score 1):

Consider deploying on GAE, which is free for small sites.

http://code.google.com/intl/da/appengine/articles/app-engine-patch.html

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to develop with the help of the vast number of modules in [CPAN](http://cpan.org/), then [Catalyst - Web Framework](http://www.catalystframework.org/) is a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the Dynamic Data Site in Visual Studio 2010, which does the same thing like Django-admin site. It requires Entity Framework.